# Keep Check box Checked Userform

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, userform

Currently, I have created a user form with three check boxes. These check boxes activate modules I have created. When I check the box in the user form I want the box to stay checked or unchecked. Any thoughts?

Comment: does the checkbox not stay check when you check it?

Comment: are you unloading the form or something? checkboxes stay checked by default... what are we missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the spreadsheet remains open, `Me.Hide` instead of `Unload Me` will do the trick, but once closed, the spreadsheet won't be able to remember the settings any more.

If you want the spreadsheet to remember the settings, even if it's closed, the selection settings need to be captured somewhere.

Let's say we created a sheet named "chkboxVal". We can then store the data there through `Ok_Click` event/procedure, and get the data back through the `UserForm_Initialize()` section.

The code will look like this:

```
Private Sub Ok_Click()
    Dim ctrl As Control, i As Integer
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
       If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
           i = i + 1
           Sheets("chkboxVal").Cells(i, 1) = ctrl.Value
       End If
    Next
    Unload Me
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim ctrl As Control, i As Integer
    For Each ctrl In UserForm1.Controls
       If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then
           i = i + 1
           ctrl.Value = Sheets("chkboxVal").Cells(i, 1)
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You might also want hide the "chkboxVal" sheet in a way that users aren't able to unhide it. If so, just add this line in the module.

```
Sheets("chkboxVal").Visible = xlVeryHidden
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have an "Unload Me" or "Unload Userform#" before you are trying to call the modules. This will reset the userform to the default.

You can also change the default (check/unchecked) for each checkbox. While building the userform, click on the checkbox, and in theproperties window, select if you want it to be set as true or false as the default.

Comment: Meh. Could be right, could be wrong. Nobody can tell. Question isn't answerable as it stands - why even bother?

Comment: Where would this be located?